# Oracle: Rename/replace object type and its references

Tags: oracle, plsql, alter

I have created an object type as below and has used in several stored procedures and in tables as a column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SS_EMP_TP FORCE AS OBJECT (
    NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    AGE NUMBER
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SS_EMP_TAB_TP AS TABLE OF SS_EMP_TP;
/
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_S ADD (EMP_DETAIL_TABLE **SS_EMP_TAB_TP**)  
      NESTED TABLE EMP_DETAIL_TABLE STORE AS  NESTED_EMP_DETAIL_TABLE RETURN AS LOCATOR;
```

Now I have to rename the object types from **SS_EMP_TP, SS_EMP_TAB_TP to EMP_TP, EMP_TAB_TP** respectively.
And also have to replace all the places where it has been referenced.

Is there a rename alter object type statement?

How can I do this? And what are all the things I need to consider while doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you not to do that. Why would you? What's the difference (apart from SS_)? What benefit do you expect?

Anyway: rename  `SS_EMP_TP` to `EMP_TP`. Everything, that references `SS_EMP_TP`, will be invalidated. Then modify each invalid object in order to fix that. Repeat.

Once again - don't, unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Thanks @@LittleFoot, `SS_` is nothing but **source system** name. 
So wanted to have a single type instead of having multiple types for different systems. Is there a `rename` alter object type statement?

Comment: You can still have it without changing anything. True, it would look *prettier* if there wasn't that "SS_" prefix (I presume that's SCOTT_ or PLUSZARA_ or something like that), but - as far as usability is concerned - it'll work just fine. If you insist, create a **synonym** (`create synonym emp_tp for ss_emp_tp;`) and use it instead of the "original" type name.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting OP use [Oracle's RENAME command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9021.htm#SQLRF01608) - if so, that only works on tables, views, sequences, and private synonyms. Attempts to 'RENAME' a type will fail with an "ORA-03001 - unimplemented feature" exception.

Comment: @@Bob, I can try the suggestion of `creating synonym` but still wondering how to give a `rename` statement for an object type. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: DROP + CREATE. Won't be easy (due to cascading). For the n-th time: it's not worth it.

Comment: @Bob: thank you, I was indeed suggesting RENAME, without consulting documentation. Obviously, that won't even work, which is yet another +1 reason why not to do it at all. At least, I wouldn't, but 1pluszara can (best of luck!).

Comment: @1pluszara: You cannot use the RENAME command with an object type - doing so is not supported, and will not work. If you don't want to use a synonym your only option, as far as I'm aware, is to create a new type with the new name, then go through the entire database, replacing references to the old type with references to the new type - then drop the old type. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @@Littlefoot and @@Bob, I'm going to try out with synonym if not go with creating a new type and drop the old one!!

Comment: Ok, best of luck!